# DevExpress XtraScheduler custom mapping

Tags: mapping, devexpress

Is it possible to make some conversion while mapping?

> SchedulerStorage schedulerStorage =
>   schedulerControl1.Storage;
>   schedulerStorage.Appointments.Mappings.Start
>   = "StartTime";

For example I want to add one hour to Appointment.Start, but I don't want to change  "StartTime" property get{} of my business object.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we did not consider such scenario of using the XtraScheduler when designed it.  So, this feature is not supported.  I can only suggest that you create a new field in the DataSource which will contain an updated value of the StartTime field and map the Start property to it....